# Construct a reccurence relation for the number of involutions in the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I don't really know where to start.

I know that an involution is a permutation that contains only 1-cycles and 2-cycles.

And also that If $σ$ is an involution then $σ^2$ = $σ_I$ and $σ^{-1}$ = σ
. Not sure what to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose you have the number of involutions in each of the symmetric groups $S_1,S_2,\ldots, S_{n-1}$. Consider the involutions in $S_n$, and note that $n$ (the index being permuted) is either in a $1$-cycle or a $2$-cycle. How many involutions are in the former case, and how many are in the latter case?

Comment: So when the nth index is a part of a 1-cycle, it will be the same as S_{n-1}. Not sure about the 2-cycle case, will it be (n-1*)S_{n-1}? Since there will be n-1 ways to get a 2-cycle?

Comment: @MarkS For the 2-cycle case you are close; I think you should replace $S_{n-1}$ with $S_{n-2}$.

Comment: Right, why is it $S_{n-2}$ and not$S_{n-1}$?

Comment: @MarkS If $n$ is in a 2-cycle, then you have $n-2$ remaining indices to put into 1-cycles and 2-cycles to complete the involution, so the number of ways to do that is the number of involutions of size $n-2$.